# SwiftUI: How to use `!` operator before `$` bindable object operator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

> I'm unable to use logical not `!` operator with Bindable `$` object.

Here is the scenario I want-

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var isLoggedIn:Bool = true
var body: some View {

    Text("Root View")
        .sheet(isPresented: !self.$isLoggedIn) {
            SignInView()
        }
        .onAppear { self.performAuthentication() }
   }
}
```

Sign In View should present as soon as I set `isLoggedIn = false` by some button action. For which I have to use logical not operator before `$`.

> Compiler error: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to
>   expected argument type 'Bool'

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I answered on similar question before, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58936606/12299030)

Comment: it is worth to mention that '$' in not 'bindable object operator'. If you have @somePropertyWrapper var value:Value = ..., $ prefix operator gives you its projectedValue. You can get a binding from a State by accessing its binding property. You can also use the $ prefix operator with any property of a State to create a binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in comment to question there were approach posted for [SwiftUI: transform Binding into another Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58936606/12299030). If you, however, want to have it explicitly as operator, you can use the following (tested & works with Xcode 11.2)

```
extension Binding where Value == Bool {
    static prefix func !(_ lhs: Binding<Bool>) -> Binding<Bool> {
        return Binding<Bool>(get:{ !lhs.wrappedValue }, 
                             set: { lhs.wrappedValue = !$0})
    }
}
```

Comment: redefining ! operator woks, but i don't think it is good idea. you are better to avoid such a solution ...

Comment: @user3441734 Why? It's a great idea (I like this even better than the earlier `negate` method).

Comment: @matt it works, for sure. but without seeing its definition, it could be little bit unclear, especially the set part. !someBool generally don't change the value. it was a nice discussion about someInt++ a year ago, and !someBindigToBool looks for me more "unpredictable"

Comment: @user3441734 That's a fair point! You're saying that the advantage of `negate` is that it can be clearer that it _produces a new binding_. In fact one might argue just the opposite of what I just said, and suggest that we call that method `negativeBinding` or similar to make absolutely clear what it does.

Comment: @matt .-) yes.  let say ! operator is prefix operator which return negated value, but don't change original value. that is what i will expect ...  even negativeBinding sounds strange, maybe bindingNegativeValue sounds better.

Comment: @matt see where the guys would like to go ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079776/swiftui-depend-on-multiple-conditions/60080083#60080083

Comment: These `Binding<Bool>`s can be replaced with `Self` and `.init`. `lhs` is not an accurate name, and it does not require a `_`.